# Ignore special characters in an XML file parse

Tags: json, xml, vlookup

I am looking at ignoring special character in a specific XML format. I have a csv file that contains "Part Numbers" and it is looking in the XML file for "Part Numbers" then is giving me an output for "Brand ID".

In the csv file there are no special characters, but in the XML file there are special characters, specifically "-".

My code is below. Everything is working except ignoring the special characters in the XML file.

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const parser = require('xml2json');
const { parseList } = require("./utils/helpers");
const lodash = require("lodash");
const csv = require("fast-csv");
const file ='4E-2022-10-24-Pies';
const PiesfilePath = path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  `${file}.xml`
);
const imagefilePath = path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  "4E-2022-10-24-Image.csv"
);

const output = fs.createWriteStream(
  `images-map.txt`,
  {
    flags: "a",
  }
);
//output.write('B15 B20 P05 P10 P15\n');

const timer = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const init = async () => {
  var PIEs='';
   const ImagesArray = await parseList(imagefilePath);
   const digitalAssets = [];


 fs.readFile( PiesfilePath, function(err, data) {
     PIEs = parser.toJson(data);

     PIEs = JSON.parse(PIEs);
   //  console.log(PIEs.PIES.Items);
     for (let i = 0; i <PIEs.PIES.Items.Item.length ; i += 1) { //
      let item = PIEs.PIES.Items.Item[i];
    //  if(item?.DigitalAssets){
      digitalAssets.push({
        "PartNumber":item.PartNumber,
        "BrandAAIAID": item.BrandAAIAID,
      })


     // console.log(item);
     }


const digitalAssetsDic =  lodash.mapKeys(digitalAssets, "PartNumber");


     for (let z = 0; z <ImagesArray.length ; z += 1) { 
      let Image= ImagesArray[z]; 
      let digitalAsset = digitalAssetsDic[Image.PartNumber];
      if(digitalAsset){
        let imagefile = Image.ImageName;
        
        output.write(`${Image.PartNumber} ${digitalAsset.BrandAAIAID} ${imagefile} ${imagefile.includes('_Fro')?'P04':'P01'} ${imagefile.split(".")[1]}\n`);

      }

     

     }


   // 
 });

 
  //let productsfull = await parseList(inputPath2);
  //const productsDec= lodash.mapKeys(products,"itemId");


};

init();
```